# How to split the string and get rid of the character between

Tags: bash, shell

this is a line of my final data:

> aodv-node-0-0.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap_MAC_sort.txt 9.051614
>   DA:00:00:00:00:00:03 SA:00:00:00:00:00:01 10.0.0.1.49154
>   10.0.0.9.50003: UDP, length 512

I would like to have an output like below:

> node-0 9.051614 00:00:00:00:00:03 00:00:00:00:00:01 10.0.0.1 49154
>   10.0.0.9 50003 UDP 512

I've read about splitting one string into two variables, but actually i don't need to use them later as variables so maybe there is any method to just cut some parts of the string and in case: **10.0.0.1.49154** just to split it into two strings and get rid of the point in the middle. (i need the IP and the port number in different columns).

Thanks for any tip

Comment: You sure it's a single line, not 2 or 3?

Comment: yes, it's just one line

Comment: `awk`, `python` or `perl` would probably be good places to start...

Comment: What are the conditions for extracting something like `node-0` from `aodv-node-0-0.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap_MAC_sort.txt`?

Comment: Could you add a few more line examples so the format is more clear

Comment: you said, it's just a single line. Then why it looks like two?

Answer (score 1):

This Gawk script

```
gawk -F ' ' '0; END { print gensub(/[.].*$/, "", "g", $1),
    $2,
    gensub(/^DA:/, "", "g", $3),
    gensub(/^SA:/, "", "g", $4),
    gensub(/[.][^.]*$/, "", "g", $5),
    gensub(/^.*[.]/, "", "g", $5),
    gensub(/[.][^.]*$/, "", "g", $6),
    gensub(/:/, "", "g", gensub(/^.*[.]/, "", "g", $6)),
    gensub(/,$/, "", "g", $7),
    $9 }' file
```

would process the last line of a file and produce an output like

```
aodv-node-0-0 9.051614 00:00:00:00:00:03 00:00:00:00:00:01 10.0.0.1 49154 10.0.0.9 50003 UDP 512
```

It could be made more compatible with simpler Awks but you get the concept. Surely everyone would find it easy to base upon from.

This version gets a lone `node-0` but I'm not sure if it's the right way you want it done:

```
gawk -F ' ' '0; END { sub(/[.].*$/, "", $1); sub(/aodv-/, "", $1); sub(/-[0-9]$/, "", $1);
    print $1,
        $2,
        gensub(/^DA:/, "", "g", $3),
        gensub(/^SA:/, "", "g", $4),
        gensub(/[.][^.]*$/, "", "g", $5),
        gensub(/^.*[.]/, "", "g", $5),
        gensub(/[.][^.]*$/, "", "g", $6),
        gensub(/:/, "", "g", gensub(/^.*[.]/, "", "g", $6)),
        gensub(/,$/, "", "g", $7),
        $9 }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is in a single line like this,

```
aodv-node-0-0.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap_MAC_sort.txt 9.051614 DA:00:00:00:00:00:03 SA:00:00:00:00:00:01 10.0.0.1.49154 10.0.0.9.50003: UDP, length 512
```

then you may run the below GNU `sed` command to get the desired output,

```
sed -r 's/^[^-]*-([^-]*?-.)[^ ]* ([0-9\.]+) DA:([^ ]*) SA:([^ ]*) ([0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3})\.([0-9]+) ([0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3})\.([0-9]+):(.*)$/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8\9/g' file | sed -r 's/^([^,]*),.* ([0-9]+)$/\1 \2/g'
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'aodv-node-0-0.pcap_udp_filtered.pcap_MAC_sort.txt 9.051614 DA:00:00:00:00:00:03 SA:00:00:00:00:00:01 10.0.0.1.49154 10.0.0.9.50003: UDP, length 512' | sed -r 's/^[^-]*-([^-]*?-.)[^ ]* ([0-9\.]+) DA:([^ ]*) SA:([^ ]*) ([0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3})\.([0-9]+) ([0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3}\.[0-9]{,3})\.([0-9]+):(.*)$/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8\9/g' | sed -r 's/^([^,]*),.* ([0-9]+)$/\1 \2/g'
node-0 9.051614 00:00:00:00:00:03 00:00:00:00:00:01 10.0.0.1 49154 10.0.0.9 50003 UDP 512
```